# Non-numerical computation of ground state energy and quasiparticle dispersion in lattice models

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, quantum-spin, lattice-model, lattice-gauge-theory

Recently I have been quite confused in determining a phase transition for anyons in Toric Code model. Here the ground state does not have any *particle*, and loops (in real and dual lattice, which for $Z_2$ are equivalent) proliferate. This means $A_s=1$ and $B_p = 1$ in the Ground State, with which you can give some thought to convince yourself that only closed loops are allowed in the configuration.

Also note, Elementary excitations are a pair of plaquettes or pair of sites with respectively $B_p = -1$ and $A_s = -1$ at the end of an open string.

Now consider the following:
$$H = -J_s \sum_{site} A_s -J_p \sum_{plaquette} B_p -\lambda_x \sum_{edge} \sigma_i^{x} \tag 1$$
Where I have added a uniform magnetic field along-$x$ in the Toric Code.

I wish to obtain ground state energy, and the dispersion for 1-particle state, under perturbation.

Now the question is following -

- I have found some perturbative approach in the literature to obtain that by various method using Perturbative Continous Unitary Transformation (p-CUT) and Series Expansion for strong-coupling & weak-coupling at $T=0$, but they harness numerical evaluation of the series under consideration. I don't want that.
- What are other ways to compute these quantities by hand? Even reference to suitable literature should be fine.
- Even if one does real-space Renormalization of this model by coarse-graining - how does one properly define that 1-particle dispersion under scaling?

For more detail please refer to - [Perturbed Toric Code](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/761790/equivalence-between-magnetically-perturbed-toric-code-and-2d-transverse-field-is)